# Cannot create a json file that accept accent, even with utf-8 encoding

Tags: json, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I try to edit a json file (encoded in utf-8, says notepad++), but all the french accent inside are destroyed doing it. I cannot find any help with this problem on internet, could somebody help me ? Getting a little crazy..

my json file is test.json and it has only one line :
{"old": "bât_1"}

I try :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
newdict = {'new':'bât_2'}
with open('test.json') as inputdata:
    data = json.load(inputdata, encoding = 'utf-8')
data.update(newdict)
with open('test.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as fid:
    json.dump(data, fid)
```

and if I open again test.json, I get:
{"old": "b\u00c3\u00a2t_1", "new": "b\u00e2t_2"}

Thank you for any help

Comment: Use `ensure_ascii=False` in `json.dump`.

Comment: trying :  
```with open('test.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as fid:
    json.dump(data, fid, ensure_ascii=False)``` 
I get :
 {"old": "bÃ¢t_1", "new": "bât_2"}
 still not what I want. I need :  {"old": "bât_1", "new": "bât_2"}

Comment: Your old data wasn’t written as utf8. Did you create it with an editor and not save it in utf8 encoding?  Write it the same way as the new data.

Comment: I'm using notepad++, I did convert the json to utf-8, and saved it, so I don't know what I could do more..